# bat files/ Shell script in windows mobile

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I have command line script.This command line script & want to run in the Windows Mobile 6.5.

I created MYWMA.cmd or MYMWA.bat

```
 \Windows\CrEme\bin\CrEme.exe -Of -classpath \Windows\CrEme\lib\AWTclasses.zip;\XONTMWA\lib\j4205328.zip oracle.apps.mwa.awt.client.StartGUI
```

How we can run this without typing in the commandline each & everytime.

This script is working fine with the command-line.

Please Help me....

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [shortcut file](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/213) to `\Windows\CrEme\bin\CrEme.exe` with the arguments you need?

If you want to create it programmatically, the function [SHCreateShortcutEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453681.aspx) may help.